# Access Model from Controller - Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am a newbie to Laravel. Please excuse me if this question sounds kiddish.

I have a model

```
class Config extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = 'configs';

}
```

and the controller goes as

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    Public function getIndex ()
    {
        $config_items = Config::all ();
        var_dump ( $config_items );
        return View::make ( 'user.userindex' )
                        -> with ( 'title', 'User Page' );
    }

}
```

But when i try to access the Config model, i am getting the error:

**Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Config\Repository::all()**

[image: Error Message]

Please help!

*I know this question could help many Laravel 4 newbies like me and my co-workers, so please help!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Config is a reserved keyword used by laravel to manage config files, so please try changing the model name to something else

Answer (score 8):

As the commenter pointed out, `Config` is actually a class that's already defined / used.

You have two options:

#### Option 1:

Namespace your `Config` model:

```
<?php namespace My\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Config extends Model { ... }
```

Then in your controller:

```
$config_items = My\Models\Config::all();
```

**Note:** If you go with option 1 (I suggest you do), you'll need to set up autoloading for your namespaced library. See this blog article on [setting up your own Laravel library with autoloading](http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading).

#### Option 2:

Don't use `Config` as a model name:

```
<?php

class Configuration extends Eloquent { ... }
```

Then in your controller:

```
$config_items = Configuration::all();
```

Hope that helps!